# Screen does not read /etc/profile.d on startup

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, alias

Whenever I start `screen`, my alias definitions in `/etc/profile.d` are missing within `screen`.

How can I make `screen` read/source all files in `/etc/profile.d/` on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure the `shell` option to run a login shell:

```
echo 'shell -/bin/bash' > ~/.screenrc
```